# Dynamic Excel Function to Identify Row Number without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I am attempting to create a static table in Excel that functions dynamically based off of a pivot table. The amount of data is manageable, ~200-300 rows, so having the formulas wrapped in IFERROR to keep them blank is not an issue. The issue I am running into is identifying the row number that the subtotal's are populated in. They are split by client but the number of entries can very month to month so this month the subtotal for client A could be row 46, but next month it could be row 52. The data is needed from the subtotal line to perform additional calculations within the "static" table.

So far I have been able to concat the row function, which correctly identifies that there is 1 row containing the data.

`=ROWS(CONCAT(VLOOKUP(G47,Table1[[CWShortID]:[Company Name]],2,FALSE)," ","Total"))`

However, I am unable to pull back the row number itself (which I need to concat into another formula).

Essentially I am attempting to use a short id to pull the clients full name from another table, concat it with " Total" to form the search parameter, return the row number of the match, then concat that with a column identifier to perform the intended calculation. Example:

`=SUM(I47/IF(COUNTIF($A$52,CONCAT(VLOOKUP(G47,Table1[[CWShortID]:[Company Name]],2,FALSE)," ","Total"))=1,$B$52,""))`

Basically in the above I need both "52"'s to be dynamically populated by the function. Reading Microsoft's documentations ROW() appears to be what I am looking for, but when nesting it doesn't work as intended.

`=SUM(I47/IF(COUNTIF(CONCAT("A",ROW(CONCAT(VLOOKUP(G47,Table1[[CWShortID]:[Company Name]],2,FALSE)," ","Total"))),CONCAT(VLOOKUP(G47,Table1[[CWShortID]:[Company Name]],2,FALSE)," ","Total"))=1,CONCAT("B",ROW(CONCAT(VLOOKUP(G47,Table1[[CWShortID]:[Company Name]],2,FALSE)," ","Total"))),""))`

Anyone ever been able to do this without having to write in VBA routines or functions? I would prefer to stick strictly with Excel formulas.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f?

Comment: Take a look at the `GETPIVOTDATA` function

Comment: OMG I could kiss you! Thank you!